# Asset versioning/Browser cache busting with Encore, Slim, and Twig

Tags: php, slim, slim-3, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony's Webpack Encore package to manage assets within a Slim 3 project with Twig templates.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#webpack-encore

I need to be able to utilize the asset versioning and cache-busting mechanisms (which automatically work if you are building a Symfony app).

I have set `.enableVersioning(true)` in the webpack.config.js which produces versioned assets, but then these cannot be located within Twig views in my Slim application using something like `<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: No experience with slim, but in symfony you would usually use `encore_entry_script_tag('app')` or `encore_entry_link_tag` instead of `asset`. These [don't work](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/versioning.html#loading-assets-from-entrypoints-json-manifest-json) I gather?

Comment: No, those particular functions are helpers that only work inside of symfony projects.